# iOS 7 style pop-up/alertview with UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

Is there a specific class for this? I don't think I can subclass the UIAlertView class (according to Apple).

[image]

thanks

Comment: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: I remember in WWDC 2013 they said that you can add custom view using content view property.

Comment: @ManicMonkOnMac Yes, the 1st beta had that option but it was removed in another beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like rmaddy said in the comment.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

I am currently using this in an app I am building. Works great.

Comment: nice! thank rmaddy though. He pointed it out before I got here. I just agreed and made it more visual :)